Unable to Fetch Data from External API in Express.js Application
I'm working on an Express.js application and facing an issue when trying to fetch data from the GitHub API using Axios. The strange part is that when I use curl from the command line with the same request, it works perfectly and returns the expected data.
curl -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer github_pat_******" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" "https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
However, making the request from within my Express.js app using Axios results in an error. This is the configuration for the axiosInstance:
let axiosConfig: {
  baseURL: string;
  timeout: number;
  headers: {
    Authorization: string;
    Accept: string;
  };
  proxy?: {
    protocol: string;
    host: string;
    port: number;
  };
  httpsAgent?: https.Agent;
  httpAgent?: http.Agent;
} = {
  baseURL: GITHUB_API_URL,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
    Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
  },
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({keepAlive: true}),
  httpAgent: new http.Agent({keepAlive: true}),
};

if (process.env.ENABLE_PROXY === "true") {
  axiosConfig = { 
    ...axiosConfig,
    proxy: {
      protocol: "http",
      host: "${PROXY_SERVER}",
      port: PROXY_PORT,
    },
  };
}

const axiosInstance = axios.create(axiosConfig);

This is how I call using axios:
const commitsUrl = `/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/commits?since=${since}`;
const response = await axiosInstance.get(commitsUrl);

I have to mention that I am running the application in a VDI connected to a proxy server, thus I configured axios to also run through the same proxy. After making the request, I receive the following error:
Error fetching file changes: AxiosError: socket hang up
    at Function.AxiosError.from (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:92:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:620:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.<computed> (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:49:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:526:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at Axios.request (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:45:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getFileChangesSinceDate (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/src/services/githubService.ts:65:22)
    at async fetchFileChangesSinceDate (/home/cdragomi/test-githubapi/express-ts-app/src/controllers/commitController.ts:25:25) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 5000,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      Authorization: 'Bearer github_pat_***********************',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.7',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    proxy: { protocol: 'http', host: 'proxy******', port: **** },
    method: 'get',
    url: '/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _events: {
      close: undefined,
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      prefinish: undefined,
      finish: undefined,
      drain: undefined,
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      socket: [Array],
      timeout: undefined,
      abort: undefined
    },
    _writableState: WritableState {
      highWaterMark: 65536,
      length: 0,
      corked: 0,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      pendingcb: 0,
      [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
      [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
    },
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object: null prototype],
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      family: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: [Object],
      hostname: 'proxy******',
      port: ****,
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits',
      search: '?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      _header: 'GET https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer github_pat_***********************\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.7.7\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'host: api.github.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'proxy******',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
      [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kSocket)]: [Socket],
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 65536,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ionutdr23/test-githubapi/commits?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z',
    _timeout: null,
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error: socket hang up
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:526:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  }
}
ERROR: Error fetching file changes:
GET /file-changes?since=2024-10-21T00:00:00.000Z 500 35.768 ms - 41

EDIT: After replacing axios with node-fetch, it worked perfectly. If anyone has the same problem, give it a try.
